# condition for whether a field exists in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series

I want to draw a timeseries graph in Timelion of Kibana.

For example, below checks for documents which have rating equal to 5.

```
.es(index='database', timefield='booking_time', q='rating:5')
```

I want to draw only those documents which have a specific field in it.

In discover tab, I know how to do it, `_exists_:field_name`.

but I don't know how to do it in Timelion expression.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer,

The `q=` parameter can be used like the discover tab in Kibana.

So,

```
.es(index='database', timefield='booking_time', q='rating:5 AND _exists_:field_name')
```